# How to format a Swift 3 nsmeasurement string to at most 2 decimal places after conversion?

Tags: swift

I would like to know how to round nsmeasurement after conversion from a unitmass. From Kilograms to Pounds for example and rounding to the 2nd decimal place instead of giving me the exact.

```
 var x = Measurement(value:19, unit: UnitMass.kilograms)
 x.convert(to:UnitMass.Pounds)
 x.description // "41.8878639834918 lb"
```

I'd like it to be 41.89

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By using a [`MeasurementFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/measurementformatter):

```
var x = Measurement(value:19, unit: UnitMass.kilograms)
x.convert(to:UnitMass.pounds)
x.description // 41.8878639834918 lb

let m = MeasurementFormatter()
m.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
m.string(from: x) // 41.89 lb
```

Comment: Also similarly related...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313408/swift-3-custom-extension-of-ns-measurement-ex-sheeps-to-goats

Comment: @user805981 that is very funny requirement :D

Comment: haha it is... might as well learn more about nsmeasurements... also coming back to this question... the numberFormatter converts it automatically to the locale? Is there a way to manually set the locale of the conversion within the formatter??

Comment: @user805981 yes. Both the MeasurementFormatter as well as the NumberFormatter have a `locale` property, e.g. https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/numberformatter/1416967-locale

Comment: Creating a new `NumberFormatter` is not necessary as `MeasurementFormatter` already has one. So `m.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2` will suffice.