# Swift 3 Custom extension of ns measurement? Ex. Sheeps to goats

Tags: swift, swift3

Custom sheeps to goats conversions in ns measurement?

How do I extend swift's measurement library to account for a custom unit of conversion?

Example is I want to convert sheeps to goats.

Comment: Goats have 60 chromosomes, but sheep only have 54. That seems like a dangerous conversion to me :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdimension

Example implementation:

```
class Animal : Dimension {
    static let sheep = Animal(symbol: "Sh", converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 2.0))
    static let goat = Animal(symbol: "Go", converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 1.0))
    static let elephant = Animal(symbol: "El", converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 100.0))

    override class func baseUnit() -> Animal {
        return Animal.goat
    }
}

var x = Measurement(value:5, unit: Animal.sheep) // 5.0 Sh
x.convert(to: Animal.goat) // 10.0 Go
x.convert(to: Animal.elephant) // 0.1 El
```